# substitute env var in sed

Tags: bash, sed

i have this **script.sh**

```
export teste=$(pwd)
echo "$teste"
sed -i 's/\String path[^w].*/String path = "$teste";/g' index.tmp
```

but the substituion stays like this

**index.tmp**

```
String path = "$teste";
```

I searched but I did not find anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

After the post i see a question that help me and my solution was this

**sed -i "s~String path[^w].*~String path = $teste;~g" index.tmp**